# How to add more properties to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have an object being created in the class library file like this:

```
var that = this.request("RequestGetParticipants");

that.name = params && params.name || "";
that.URI = params && params.URI || "";
```

Now I would like to add a property called ID that is already included in the object returned from the above code can I just add:

```
that.ID = params && params.ID || "";

return that;
```

I have already tried doing this but when I go to store the ID in a variable and type something like `var myID = that.ID; or myID = that.ID.tostring();`  it returns an empty string.  Please help I am a newcomer to js.

Comment: Check the `params` object. Maybe its missing the `ID` property. Also, use ternary operator like: `that.ID = (params && params.ID) ? params.ID : "-";`

Answer (score 0):

it depends what is being returned from `this.request("RequestGetParticipants")`. The code you have is correct for a normal object `{}` but if there are custom properties on your object, you may be overwriting it.

This works for me

```
var that = {};
that.name = "jasonscript";
that.URI = "stackoverflow.com";
that.ID = "SO";

console.log(that.ID);
```

I would look at what is returned from `this.request("RequestGetParticipants")`
Alternatively, try a different name so instead of

```
that.ID = "SO";
```

try

```
that.myID = "SO";
```

and see if that works.